# django vs qlik sense: naming the ID field "id" vs "table1_id"

Tags: django, qliksense

Qlik sense recommends that each table's primary key be named something like "table1_id" if the table name is Table1. This allows their "automatic association" to properly detect like-named fields and link them.

On the other hand, the django best practice is to just use the default primary key name "id" for each table, e.g. table named Table1 will have a field called "id", same for a table named Table2, etc.

As such, a django-managed database will not yield optimal ID field names for Qlik Sense's automatic association.

What's the best practice among Qlik Sense + Django users?

Answer (score 0):

You can always define your own AutoField with primary_key=True and call it whatever you like. What's more, you can then refer to that field via the `.pk` alias so it will work for any model.

Comment: Thats most likely what im going to end up doing, but it's such a hassle to add primary keys to all the models when it's a large database. +1 for using .pk

Comment: Doing this generates a migration that removes the original "id" field

Comment: I guess this method requires that I replace the automatic migration with my own manual one that renames "id" to "table1_id"

Comment: Actually, the following field would generate an automatic migration that just renames the field: `table1_id = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name="ID")  `

Comment: This doesn't work for models with camel-case. Reported [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29378#ticket)